# How many bytes is a contract variable like IERC20 public token?

Tags: solidity

when I initialize variable like this:

```
IERC20 public token;
```

how many bytes is it? Does it take entire slot in memory or can it be combined with other variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really only an address in storage.

You can pack it with up to 12 other bytes in a single slot.

You can verify it easily with this sample code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {

}

contract PackInterface {

  // Address : 20 bytes stored in slot 0 (20 / 32)
  IERC20 public token;

  // 12 bytes stored in slot 0 (32 / 32)
  uint96 packed;

  // 1 byte stored in slot 1 (1 / 32)
  uint8 notPacked;

  function getSlots() public view returns (uint256 tokenSlot, uint256 packedSlot, uint256 notPackedSlot) {
    assembly {
      tokenSlot := token.slot
      packedSlot := packed.slot
      notPackedSlot := notPacked.slot
    }

    // Returns 0, 0, 1
  }

}
```

I hope that answers your question.